# Windows Azure Web Site Status Limited

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am aware that this question is asked before but Azure Status Dashboard shows all of the services are running as expected. However, all of my websites are marked as Limited. I can reach 1 one of them but cannot other 3. To test the issue, I have created a new web site on azure and its status is set to Running. My websites are located in Europe West servers.

Is it a outage problem or something wrong with my apps ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is an outage [Partial Degradation] for Azure Website. Check out the [Windows Azure Service Dashboard](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/)

[image: Azure Website Outage - East Europe]

Comment: thank you. it was saying "Service is running normally" just an hour ago.